# backstretch javascript iphone issue bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, css, templates, twitter-bootstrap

I have the BACKGROUND image doing everything I need correctly (because I am running Backstretch JS) on computer and ipad but when it comes to phones, it does not look so well? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated..

http://www.closetvip.com/splash.html

I am using backstrech js for the background image

Comment: What happens on iphone

Comment: the picture is cocked all the way to right for some reason? it looks good on computer and device and Backstrech claims it sizes 100% leaves me a little dumb founded?

Comment: can i see the background css

Comment: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ no background css?

Answer (score 0):

I have some changed in your code so please add this ID and Class.

```
#spanish {
position: absolute;
left: 200;
bottom: 100px;
float: right;
}
#english {
position: absolute;
bottom: 101px;
float: left;
}
```

You have use this css only for iPhone css not for all screen.